# Wrong number of arguments while calling method in different RSpec contexts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

Here is my little problem that makes me feel stupid. I'm testing my rails application with RSpec and I also have devise controller helper (grabbed from the Devise wiki, note **user** default parameter):

```
module ControllerMacros
  module ControllerHelpers
    def sign_in(user=mock_model(User))
      if user.nil?
        request.env['warden'].stub(:authenticate!).
          and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
        controller.stub :current_user => nil
      else
        # Lots of user.stub here
        controller.stub :current_user => user
      end
    end
  end

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.include ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
  end
end
```

Now when I use **sign_in** in one context of my controller test everything works fine:

```
context "Authorized access" do
    before(:each) do
      mocked_user = mock_model(User)
      mocked_user.stub(:is?).with(:admin).and_return(true)
      sign_in(mocked_user)
      # some checks 
    end
end
```

But in another context (in the same spec) I'm getting "**wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)**":

```
context "Unauthorized access" do
 before(:each) do
   sign_in(nil)
 end

# test cases
end
```

And it's rather confusing for me, because I'm passing only one(nil) argument. I'll be glad to hear any suggestions, because these two calls look the same for me. Maybe I`m missing something.

**UPDATE**:

1. Rails 3.1.0
2. ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570)
3. RSpec 2.7.1

**UPDATE 2(error example):**

```
 Failure/Error: sign_in(nil)
   ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
   # ./spec/support/controller_macros.rb:5:in `sign_in'
   # ./spec/controllers/forum/topics_controller_spec.rb:93:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message, please?

Comment: From the devise wiki - "At the time of writing no gem version of rspec-mocks doesn't support throw parameters, so you'll need to use the git repository in the meantime (alongside rspec and rspec-rails 2.8.0.rc1)." RSpec 2.8.0 was released the other day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error will be coming from the line

```
request.env['warden'].stub(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
```

RSpec versions lower than 2.8 did not support parameters for `and_throw`. Update the Gemfile to use RSpec 2.8.0 and let me know how you get on.

I remember I used a simpler method for controller tests

```
before do
  controller.stub(:authenticate!).and_return(mock_model('user'))
end
```

That way you are bypassing Devise altogether which is well tested